# bash - how do I use 2 numbers on a line to create a sequence

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have this file content:

```
2450TO3450  
3800  
4500TO4560
```

And I would like to obtain something of this sort:

```
2450  
2454  
2458  
...  
3450  
3800  
4500  
4504  
4508  
..  
4560
```

Basically I would need a one liner in `sed`/`awk` that would read the values on both sides of the `TO` separator and inject those in a `seq` command or do the loop on its own and dump it in the same file as a value per line with an arbitrary increment, let's say 4 in the example above.

I know I can use several one temp file, go the `read` command and sorts, but I would like to do it in a one liner starting with `cat filename |` etc. as it is already part of a bigger script.

Correctness of the input is *guaranteed* so always left side of `TO`is smaller than bigger side of it.

Thanks

Comment: This is not a good task for `sed` or `awk`, it will result in something pretty cryptic. Try a `python -c` one-liner, or even a small 3-line script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
awk -F TO '{system("seq " $1 " 4 " ($2 ? $2 : $1))}'
```

This would tell `awk` to `system` (execute) the command `seq 10 4 10` for lines just containing 10 (which outputs 10), and something like `seq 10 4 40` for lines like `10TO40`. The output seems to match your example.

Comment: works and is the shortest which was one of the important conditions. All awk+macros work actually. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
awk -F'TO' -v inc=4 'NF==1{print $1;next}{for(i=$1;i<=$2;i+=inc)print i}' file
```

or, if you like starting with `cat`:

```
cat file | awk -F'TO' -v inc=4 'NF==1{print $1;next}{for(i=$1;i<=$2;i+=inc)print i}'
```

Comment: this has some unexpected behavior. Not sure what is causing it yet, but it seems it is starting from 0 in some cases and it doesn't eliminate the range in itself from the output

Comment: Please share some input data that upsets it.

Comment: `2072TO2080  
2116TO2128  
2164TO2172

Comment: sorry for formatting, still getting the grips of it... Above is the input and here is the output: `2072TO2080
2076
2080

4
8 ... ` increments by 4 all the way to 2128 then it starts from 4 again

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this:

```
sed 's/TO/ /' file.txt | while read first second; do if [ ! -z "$second" ] ; then seq $first 4 $second; else printf "%s\n" $first; fi; done
```

`sed` is used to replace `TO` with space char.

`read` is used to read the line, if there are 2 numbers, `seq` is used to generate the sequence. Otherwise, the uniq number is printed.

Comment: first tried this one and seems to be working as needed. thanks. will try the others and provide feedback as well.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
txt="2450TO3450  
3800  
4500TO4560"
```

You can do:

```
echo "$txt" | awk -F TO '{$2<$1 ? t=$1 : t=$2; for(i=$1; i<=t; i++) print i}'
```

If you want an increment greater than 1:

```
echo "$txt" | awk -F TO -v p=4 '{$2<$1 ? t=$1 : t=$2; for(i=$1; i<=t; i+=p) print i}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(.*)TO(.*)/seq \1 4 \2/e' file
```

This evaluates the RHS of the substitution command if the LHS contains `TO`.